# Extend below program for acute and obtuse angle triangle | using Sine cos functions

Tags: java, if-statement

so I want to know how to make a program that will ask multiple questions and lead to multiple values or other questions to build on.

So I was building a "missing side of right triangle" program. Successful after a couple tries I wondered why not make the program solve obtuse or acute triangles. Well, I could program the law of sines and cosines. The problem is I don't know how. I learned the basics of java through 2-3 videos off youtube. I tried to make an if-else nested inside an if-else statement. But this is my code I tried to build upon:

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.lang.Math; 

public class MissingSide {

static java.util.Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args){
    int firstSideGiven = 0;
    int hypotenuseGiven = 0;
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Are you trying to figure out a missing side given the hypotenuse and another side?");
    System.out.println("Then this is the place :)");
        System.out.print("What is the value of the first side, other than the hypotenuse?");
            if (userInput.hasNextInt()) {
                firstSideGiven = userInput.nextInt();
            }else{
                System.out.println("Give me somthing else to work with!");
            }
            System.out.println("What is your hypotenuse?");
            if (userInput.hasNextInt()){
                hypotenuseGiven = userInput.nextInt();
            }else{
                System.out.print("Wait, I want you to think about what you are doing with your life.");
            }
            System.out.println("Your missing side is: " + (Math.sqrt((Math.pow(hypotenuseGiven, 2)-Math.pow(firstSideGiven, 2)))));
    }
}
```

And now I want to know what to do next, when I attempted to nest everything inside another if statement, it gave me an error I did not understand.

Comment: It'd be great if you showed us the attempt and the errors

Comment: if you're making a menu driven program, switch case can work better

Comment: In the case the user doesn’t provide an integer, wouldn’t you want either to go back and try again or to exit the program? The first requires a loop. The obvious way to exit is to put the remaining lines of the main method inside the if statement — so yes, you will have if else inside if else.

Comment: “I attempted to nest everything inside another if statement, it gave me an error I did not understand.” If you want our help with that, post the code that gave the error and the exact error message. Certainly you can put everything inside another if statement.

Comment: What error do you get? What exactly is tour question ?  (BTW `Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);` is never used)

Answer (score 0):

Well It would be great if you can share the problem and/or errors faced during the change.

Here is a basic logic to solve your issue -

You can use `Math.cos` and `Math.sin` functions to calculate function value.
These values can be used to calculate the missing side.

**Note** - Above functions accept value in [radian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian), So change your degree value to radian before usage. i.e. -

```
double angleInDegree = 354;
double angleInRadian = Math.toRadians(angleInDegree);
double cos = Math.cos(angleInRadian);
```

Hope it helps. :)